# Showing 0% Coverage in SonarQube (integration with Teamcity for .Net Project)

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, devops, dotcover

I have configured the Build steps as below

1. Created another Build Configuration (e.g. named "Send to SonarQube") and added the dependency on initial configuration

   An artifact dependency for ".teamcity/.NETCoverage/dotCover.dcvr" file and getting artifacts from "Build from the same chain".
2. In the new configuration ("Send to SonarQube") added a Command Line step with the following script:

   %teamcity.dotCover.home%\dotCover.exe report /ReportType=HTML /Source="dotCover.dcvr" /Output="dotCover.html"
3. Added SonarQube Runner to the new configuration and added additional command line argument with "-Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=dotCover.html"

Please suggest

**Note:** When i have checked the dotCover.html the coverage is showing perfectly. **But the sonarqube is showing as 0% covered**

Comment: I think without build log we won't be able to help you. Maybe try to use quotes with your paths like: "%teamcity.dotCover.home%\dotCover.exe"

Comment: 1. Quotes will not do any difference. 2. Log is showing as success but what i have identified is Sonarqube is analyzing only the JS files(Generated while converting .dcvr file to html not my build files), so Sonarqube is displaying 0%. 3. But i have tried in n no. of ways but no luck every time same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using build chains, you are probably switching directories and SonarQube uses absolute paths. To confirm this, look at the html/[nnn].html files in your working directory. In html -> head -> title, does the absolute path match the source code in your current working directory when you run the report command?

So to summarize, in your "Send to SonarQube", you need to ensure:

1. You have your source code in the working directory
2. Your individual [nnn].html files have titles with absolute paths matching the source code in your working directory.

There are a few ways to ensure #2:

Way #1

- Tell TeamCity to run all snapshot dependencies on the same agent.
- Make sure your VCS setup is exactly the same. (For myself, I had excluded some folders in my "Send To SonarQube" equivalent, and that caused a different working directory)

Way #2

- Override the Checkout Directory in your VCS setup for everything in the build chain to point to the same absolute directory.
- (I haven't tried this, but it should work across agents since the agent name isn't in the directory path)